# React Router 4 navigation pattern in a Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I am currently working on a simple React app with a very common workflow where users trigger Redux actions that, in turn, request data from an API. But since I would like to make the results of these actions persistent in the URL, I have opted for React Router v4 to help me with the job.

I have gone through the Redux integration notes in the [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/redux-integration/deep-integration) but the idea of passing the `history` object to Redux actions just doesn't feel like the most elegant pattern to me. Since both Redux and Router state changes cause React components to be re-rendered, I'm a little worried the component updates could go a bit out of control in this scenario.

So in order to make the re-rendering a bit more predictable and sequential, I have come up with the following pattern that attempts to follow the single direction data flow principle:

1. Where I used to trigger Redux actions as a result of users' interactions with the UI, I am now calling React Router's `props.history.push` to update the URL instead. The actual change is about updating a URL parameter rather than the whole route but that's probably not that relevant here.

Before:

```
// UserSelector.jsx
handleUserChange = ({ target: selectElement }) => {
  // Some preliminary checks here...

  const userId = selectElement.value

  // Fire a Redux action
  this.props.setUser(userId)
}
```

After:

```
// UserSelector.jsx
handleUserChange = ({ target: selectElement }) => {
  // Some preliminary checks here...

  const userId = selectElement.value

  // Use React Router to update the URL
  this.props.history.push(`/user-selector/${userId}`)
}
```

2. The `userId` change in the URL causes React Router to trigger a re-render of the current route.

Route definition in App.jsx:

```
<Route path="/user-selector/:userId?" component={UserSelector} />
```

3. During that re-render, a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook gets invoked. In there I am comparing the previous and current values of the URL parameter via the React Router's `props.match.params` object. If a change is detected, a Redux action gets fired to fetch new data.

Modified UserSelector.jsx:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  const { match: { params: { userId: prevUserId } } } = prevProps
  const { match: { params: { userId } } } = this.props

  if (prevUserId === userId) {
    return
  }

  // Fire a Redux action (previously this sat in the onChange handler)
  this.props.setUser(userId)
}
```

4. When the results are ready, all React components subscribed to Redux get re-rendered.

And this is my attempt to visualise how the code's been structured:

[image: Syncing URL changes with Redux]

If anyone could verify if this pattern is acceptable, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For step 3, I suggest a different approach which should be more in line with react-router:

- react-router renders a component based on a route
- this component should act as the handler based on the particular route it matches (think of this as a container or page component)
- when this component is mounted, you can use componentWillMount to fetch (or isomorphic-fetch) to load up the data for itself/children
- this way, you do not need to use componentDidUpdate to check the URL/params
- Don't forget to use componentWillUnmount to cancel the fetch request so that it doesn't cause an action to trigger in your redux state
- Don't use the App level itself to do the data fetching, it needs to be done at the page/container level

From the updated code provided in the question:

- I suggest moving the logic out, as you would most likely need the same logic for componentDidMount (such as the case when you first hit that route, componentDidUpdate will only trigger on subsequent changes, not the first render)

Comment: Thanks for your response, David - very helpful and already made me rethink some of the things in the original design (will post a modified version as soon as it's ready). Still, the description of the issue was a little confusing so I've added a few code snippets that will hopefully make things a little clearer.

Comment: Really good points there about componentWillUnmount, reusing the code between Mount and Update hooks and separating URL handling logic from presentational concerns. I've also tweaked step 2: I got rid of these unnecessary re-renders of the wrapper "route" component by removing the userId URL parameter from the path: <Route path="/user-selector" ... />. Instead, I now have a tree-like structure with nested <Route/> elements that I think is more in the spirit of Router v4. As a result only routes that care about userId have it in the route path and they are the only ones that get re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth considering whether you need to store information about which user is selected in your Redux store and as part of URL - do you gain anything by structuring the application like this? If you do, is it worth the added complexity?

Comment: Good shout John - I've already discovered I might not actually need to store that URL param in Redux that would violate the single-sources-of-truth principle. But regardless of that, the question remains whether this "do one thing at a time and do it sequentially" pattern makes sense. At the moment I'm triggering a Redux action that sets user ID in the store but behind the scenes that triggers another action that basically fetches data. So I might as well simplify it and get Redux to fetch data straight away.